# Ubuntu : Intellij : Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Ive looked around for an answer for this problem and all the solutions I have found don't work.

```sh
~ $ intellij-idea-community
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

```sh
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I am not running as root. And I'm not using headless JDK, Im using the following.

```sh
~ $ java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Ive installed intellij using `apt-get` and am currently on the most recent version. **Other jetbrains sofware works fine (pycharm, clion)**

I also have

```java
~ $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin/java             1091      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin/java             1091      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Could you please attach idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)?